# How to use Google Cast Apps by intent?

Tags: android, google-chrome, youtube, chromecast

I know that Android Youtube App and Chrome App are both support Google Cast. They have a Cast Button, if user click it, these apps will push their screen and sound to Chromecast.

I want to implement an App, which can open Youtube App and Chrome App and show them on Chromecast via Intent without click any Cast Button, is it possible? How can I to?

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no such intents available to do so.